# How can I access a method with several swing components from another class? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, methods, superclass

Suppose:

```
public class Window
{

public void Dialog ()
{
JDialog JD = new JDialog();

// add pictures/labels onto JDialog

}
}
```

And:

```
public class Main
{

//Suppose here is a GUI with a button that if clicked called the Dialog method

}
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to access the method on Eclipse. I created a constructor on the Window class to call the method but that didn't work for me.

> ```
>  Window instance1 ; // create instance of class
>    public Window (Window temp){
>      instance1 = temp;      
> }
> ```

```
///On Main Class

Dialog temp1 = new Dialog (temp1);

temp1.OpenDialog (); // calls method from other class
```

I know its a syntax issue with calling the constructor but I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: _My issue is that I cannot figure out how to access the method on Eclipse._ Java code is not IDE-dependent.

Comment: We need more  code my friend. I'm not seeing enough meat here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
public class Window
{
    public void dialog()// you re forgeting the parenttheses
    {
        JDialog JD = new JDialog();

        // add pictures/labels onto JDialog
    }
}
```

And you can access you method by:

```
public class Main{
    Window win;

    public Main(){
        win = new Window();
        win.dialog();
    }
}
```

And another thing its a convention to not use uppercase letter on the first letter of method name. First letter in uppercase is used for class constructor.

A contructor don't return any kind of variable and use the same name as Class.

Comment: Im sorry but I didn't copy paste this so the real program has parenthesis. Also I need an argument in the parenthesis to match win...

Comment: What you want to say with "to match win..."? In order to help you should clarify your question.

Comment: Nvm. I got it to work due to your help by following exactly what you done. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

In the main method, declare and initialize a `Dialog` - not a `Window`:

```
public class Main{

    Dialog instance = new Dialog();

    public Main(){    
        instance.methodWithinDialogClass();//add pictures/labels onto JDialog
    }
}
```

Your Dialog class should look like this:

```
public class Dialog{

    private Object pics;

    public Dialog(){
        //do some stuff to setup Dialog, initialize variable etc if you wish
    }

    public void methoWithinDialogClass(){
        //add pics etc to pics  
    }
}
```

I can't see what you need `Window` for - just declare and create a new `Dialog` in your main method, then you can access it.